# Dropping observations in Stata based on age and panel round

Tags: panel, stata

I have a panel dataset and I want to drop those respondents that were aged 40 years and over in their first round of the survey.

I tried doing`drop if age>40` and also `drop if age>40 & t==1` where t is an identifier of the survey wave the person is in. However when I do the second I am left with people over the age of 40.

Here is an example of how my data looks like:

```
pid      age     wave  year of survey
1         20      1      2005
1         21      2      2006
1         22      3      2007 
1         23      4      2008
2         37      1      2006 
2         38      2      2007  
2         39      3      2008
2         40      4      2009
3         40      1      2008
3         41      2      2009
3         42      3      2010
3         43      4      2011
```

My aim is not to lose the 3rd respondent given that he/she was within my target age group when they were first surveyed but they were not in the following survey years (rather than just being left with his/her first wave of data and dropping the other 3 that is what is being done if I simply do `drop if age<=40`).

Is there another way so as to be left with only people up to the age of 40 while keeping those who were 40 in their first wave even if they turn 41, 42 etc in subsequent waves? I basically want to constrain my panel into the up to 40 years of age group while keeping those who were 40 in their wave but might be over 40 in subsequent waves (I only have 4 waves).

Comment: I dropped the economics tag here, as I don't think it's helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stata gives you exactly what you're asking for. With `drop if age > 40` you simply lose **any observation** for which `age > 40`. With `drop if age > 40 & wave == 1` you add an additional condition: drop it if it simultaneously has `wave == 1`. I think that's clear.

I find your explanation somewhat contradictory. You don't want to lose any observation from respondent 3 because in her first wave she's not over 40, although she is in her following waves. But then you say you want to be left with only people up to the age of 40.

The following just drops all observations for any person who in her first wave is over 40. Let us know if this is not what you seek.

```
clear all
set more off

input ///
pid      age     wave  survyear
1         20      1      2005
1         21      2      2006
1         22      3      2007 
1         23      4      2008
2         37      1      2006 
2         38      2      2007  
2         39      3      2008
2         40      4      2009
3         40      1      2008
3         41      2      2009
3         42      3      2010
3         43      4      2011
4         42      1      2009
4         43      2      2010
4         44      3      2011
4         45      4      2012
end

list, sepby(pid)

*-----

bysort pid (age): drop if age[1] > 40
list, sepby(pid)
```

You probably want to read [Speaking Stata: How to move step by: step](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=pr0004), by Nick Cox. See also `help subscripting`.

### Edit

With no knowledge of the database structure, sorting by `wave` should be a more general approach. That involves `bysort pid (wave): ...` in the previous code. Imagine a case where a person has the same age for two consecutive waves. If so, sorting by `age` would not give consistent results. The `wave` variable is likely to be the one that uniquely identifies cases, for each person. Read `help sort` and `help isid` carefully, including the manual entries.

Comment: Many thanks. It works fine. One small clarification: when I do drop if age<40 I get the same number of respondents left as I get when I do: bysort pid (age): drop if age[1] > 40. However, with the first method, I am left with respondents that appear for less than 4 waves (that is the full duration of my panel) whereas when using your suggested method I only have respondents who are present in all 4 waves, which is what I wanted. I am puzzled as to why the number of respondents eliminated is the same in both instances but the number of waves successfully completed by each respondent differs

Comment: Your two statements cannot be equivalent! Your code as given uses different operators. More generally, we can't assess your report easily without a reproducible example.

Comment: @NickCox Many thanks for this: the tabulations are too long to paste here but what happens is that when I do drop if age>40 I am left with an (n = 2670) after doing: xttab age and with exactly the same n when I do bysort pid (age): drop if age[1] > 40. Since I want to observe everyone for 4 waves I then did: gen one=1 followed by:
egen mycount=count(new), by(pid). When I drop using the drop if age>40 command I get cases with mycount<4 waves whereas when I use the bysort option I only get cases with mycount==4.I tested other ages to test and the number of dropped cases is still the same with

Comment: both methods whereas the mycount variable again appears to differ according to the method used

Comment: Even experienced Stata users are challenged to hold stuff like that in their heads and understand it all. Without a reproducible example, which you can be as small as you like, as long as it shows what you regard as a problem, it's hard to understand what's puzzling you.

Comment: NickCox Sorry about that. Here is a quick example: with both commands I get an n=2670 when I drop respondents over 40 years of age. However, following the simple drop if age>40 command, my variable named "mycount" that counts the number of waves a person stays in my panel is as follows:    
Pid mycount
1 2
1 2
2 3
2 3
2 3
3 4
3 4
3 4
3 4
                                                                                
whereas when I do bysort pid (age): drop if age[1] > 40 the mycount variable only takes the value of 4, in other words every respondent is in the survey for 4 waves

Comment: it seems that I cannot format the table with my example in the comments area. I will attempt to read the table that was as follows: I had 4 pids namely 1, 2 and 3 and a mycount variable. Pid number 1 had a value of 2 in the mycount variable (i.e. it appeared in 2 waves), pid number 2 had a mycount 3 (i.e. appeared in 3 waves) and pid number 3 had a mycount variable value of 4 (i.e. appeared in 4 waves)

Comment: The comment section is not precisely the place you want to use to insert a table. You can try pasting it at the end of your original post, adding an EDIT subtitle or something of the sort. It's not clear to me what your doubt is. As @NickCox points out, a _reproducible_ example would help. What you give in your previous comment is **not** a reproducible example. The example in the **answer** I've given is reproducible because you can copy it, paste it in a do-file, run it, and get the exact same results I originally obtained.

Comment: With the example data in my answer, `drop if age > 40` will give
a `count` of 9 observations. With my suggested, code a `count` of
12 observations. If you are counting the number of respondents, both
pieces of code code give 3 respondents; so _it is_ possible to
get the same number of respondents with both codes.

Comment: @RobertoFerrer Many thanks for this and apologies for the confusion-I am new here and I am just starting to find my way around. Thank you for clearing this for me-it makes sense now that I could get the same number of respondents left but not the same number of observations. I am trying to understand how your suggested command operates: does it make sure I am only left with respondents that have 4 waves of completed data or is the fact that all the respondents I am left with have a wave count equal to 4 coincidental?

Comment: The code drops all observations for any respondent who is over 40 at the time of her first interview. If all respondents have 4 waves after running the code, then two things can be happening. i) Either all respondents have 4 waves initially, so whoever drops is immaterial; or ii) those who have less then 4 waves are being dropped due to the age condition. It is easy to check with the example data. Just add a 5th respondent that has 3 waves but is **not** over 40 at the time of her first interview. That respondent will **not** drop. My suggestion: play with an example while reading  help docs.